# Retrieving Multitouch Data in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, multi-touch

I am having a problem retrieving touch input on my XNA game. Here is my starting code:

```
TouchCollection touchPositions;
List<Vector2> touchReleases = new List<Vector2>();
```

Then this is my update code:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{          
    // Other update logic here

    touchReleases.Clear();
    foreach (TouchLocation tl in touchPositions) 
    {
        if (tl.State == TouchLocationState.Released) 
           touchReleases.Add(tl.Position); 
    }
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

The idea is to load all of the releases into a `Vector2` list. Then (during the draw code) a function checks for a release to do stuff.

EDIT: I tested this using `Guide.BeginShowMessageBox()` during the `foreach` loop. It popped up every time I released.

```
bool released = false;
foreach (TouchLocation tl in touchPositions)
{
    // checks to see if the button is being hovered on     
}
foreach (Vector2 tr in touchReleases)
{
    if (PointInArea(tr, new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, buttonimage[0].Width, buttonimage[0].Height))) 
    { 
        released = true; 
        break; 
    }
}
return released;
```

The `PointInArea` function checks to see if a `Vector2` is in a `Rectangle`. I know this function is working right.

What's funny is that the buttons respond to releases about once every 4 taps. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: How many `touchReleases` do you detect every cycle? I think that only one `TouchLocation` can be `Released` at a time.

Comment: Since I am running this on the Windows Phone Emulator, only one TouchLocation is triggered every time. So I am detecting just one touch every step.

Comment: Of course, but have you tried this on a device? I think that it's not possible to detect more than one `Release` every step.

Comment: Anyway, maybe you should add the code where you use `released`. Or you should test with `BeginShowMessageBox` if that behaves as you expect, too.